# The TargetControlID of 'HoverMenuExtender2' is not valid. A control with ID 'cable' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

When I am applying the column ID into targetconrtolID of Hovermenuextender its not working and error coming is

**The TargetControlID of 'HoverMenuExtender2' is not valid. A control with ID 'cable' could not be found.**

I need to display my sub menu on the column ending

the code written is here

```
<cc1:HoverMenuExtender ID="HoverMenuExtender2" runat="server" PopupControlID="ProjectMenu" TargetControlID="cable" PopupPosition="Bottom" >
                            </cc1:HoverMenuExtender>


 <td align="center" style="border: medium solid White" class="style5" id="cable">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lblmenudashboard" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Underline="False"
                                ForeColor="white" OnClick="lblmenudashboard_Click">Dashboard</asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>

<asp:Panel ID="ProjectMenu" runat="server" Visible="true" Width="210px">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="style8" align="center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lblsubMenu_Star" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Underline="False"
                                                ForeColor="white"> Project0</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lblsubMenu_Udaan" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Underline="False"
                                                ForeColor="white"> Project1</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </asp:Panel>
```

I have applied the scriptManager. Also Let me know how can I select that hovermenu so that I can open tab from their itself.

Comment: Does control with ID = cable have runat="server" attribute ?

Comment: No it was not there. Thanks its working fine.

Comment: But I need to stop that and select from tab from that menu also how can I achieve this functionality